# How does bitwise signed symbol work ~

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, frontend, bitwise-operators

So, I've looked at several websites and still don't understand what the bitwise operator ~ does.  Basically, I understand that for a number such as 4 which would be represented in binary as 100 should be flipped when you put ~4 to 011; however, there appears to be somehow become -5 then the tutorials say something about a 32-bit representation with a load a negative digit number.  At this point I am completely lost please explain how ~ works.

Comment: So you're asking what a signed number looks like in binary? I assure you it isn't random.

Comment: @DaveNewton How does it convert to -5

Comment: Please search the web for binary number representation. Twos-complement.

Answer (score 3):

The number 4 is not `100`. It's `00000000000000000000000000000100`. All those zeros are flipped to ones by `~`.

The resulting number is negative because of how those 32-bit values are interpreted when converted back to ordinary JavaScript numbers. But I'm getting ahead of myself: the first thing a bitwise operator in JavaScript does is create a *temporary* 32-bit integer value from the source number.  Then the operator does its magic, which in the case of `~` is to invert all the bits of that 32-bit value. Then the number is converted back to a 64-bit double-precision floating point value, which is the normal JavaScript numeric type.

The 32-bit values are interpreted as *signed* values, which has to do with the way computer arithmetic works. Suffice to say that any 32-bit value whose left-most (most significant) bit is a `1` is interpreted as a negative value.

Binary math and the way modern computers (well, almost all historical ones too) do it is kind-of a broad subject. Some programming languages provide abstractions that mostly hide the realities of how the computing hardware *actually* works; JavaScript is not really one of those languages in most implementations.

Comment: why does 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011 become -5 ?

Comment: Because that's how a computer interprets those 32 bits.  It's called *two's complement* arithmetic. All modern computing hardware works that way.

Comment: I think you should start your answer off with the sentence about bitwise operators converting the number to a temporary 32-bit integer. Otherwise the first paragraph feels a little weird since all numbers in JavaScript are IEEE754 64-bit doubles.

Comment: @Paulpro well I agree it's less than perfect, but the OP is apparently completely new to binary math and the realities of computing hardware. My point was in fact to be "weird" and eye-opening.

Answer (score 3):

`4` = `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100`

`~4` = `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011`

Since the leftmost bit is the [sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) in a signed 32 bit value that's where your negative values come from. Slightly related: you may also want to read up on [MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit), [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit).

Comment: Basically true but JavaScript bitwise operators work with 32-bit values, not 8-bit values.

Comment: Yeah, same principle, just didn't want to type out all 32 bits. But now I have.

Comment: Feel your pain :)

Comment: @RobIII why does 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011 become -5 ?

Comment: @user2101 Because that's how binary numbers work. Read up on [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). It has been mentioned more than once by now.